# CSS3 visual formatting model

Tags: css

I'm confused by what is written in the specification on the box model in that 
**it generates for each element 0 or more boxes** but I do not understand when an element may generate 0 box.
In fact in the specification is also said that **each element generates a box**.

Thanks.

Comment: Elements that are display:none or width:0;height:0;font-size:0;line-height:0;border:0;margin:0;padding:0 do not generate a box.

Answer (score 1):

In the following cases an element generates 0 boxes:

- The display property is set to none
- The element is a comment or nested in a comment
- The element is a processing instruction
- The element is a <head> element
- The element is a <title> element
- The element is a <script> element
- The element is a <meta> element
- The element is a <link> element